# ASWebAuthenticationSession in SWIFTUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios13, xcode11

I've been trying to figure out how to integrate an `ASWebAuthenticationSession` (to perform login via `Oauth`) with `SwiftUI`. I can't find any documentation on the same online anywhere and was wondering if someone with more SwiftUI and iOS dev experience could tell me how I can achieve something along the lines. I currently need a system for someone to click the Login button which then opens a `ASWebAuthSession` and allows the user to login before redirecting them back to my app and loading another SwiftUI view.

I have in my `ContentView` one button whos calls this function :

```
func getAuthTokenWithWebLogin() {

    let authURL = URL(string: "https://test-login.blabla.no/connect/authorize?scope=openid%20profile%20AppFramework%20offline_access&response_type=code&client_id=<blalblalba>&redirect_uri=https://integration-partner/post-login")
    let callbackUrlScheme = "no.blabla:/oauthdirect"

    webAuthSession = ASWebAuthenticationSession.init(url: authURL!, callbackURLScheme: callbackUrlScheme, completionHandler: { (callBack:URL?, error:Error?) in

        // handle auth response
        guard error == nil, let successURL = callBack else {
            return
        }

        let oauthToken = NSURLComponents(string: (successURL.absoluteString))?.queryItems?.filter({$0.name == "code"}).first

        // Do what you now that you've got the token, or use the callBack URL
        print(oauthToken ?? "No OAuth Token")
    })

    // Kick it off
    webAuthSession?.start()

}
```

But I get this error:

> Cannot start ASWebAuthenticationSession without providing presentation
>   context. Set presentationContextProvider before calling -start.

How should I do this in `SwiftUI`? Any examples would be fantastic!

Comment: I managed to do this somehow. But im into a new problem. I got a message from the server that says: [ERR] code_challenge is missing. Someone indicates that I am missing something like PKCE.

Answer (score 2):

With `.webAuthenticationSession(isPresented:content)` modifier in **[BetterSafariView](https://github.com/stleamist/BetterSafariView)**, you can easily use `ASWebAuthenticationSession` in SwiftUI. It handles the work related to providing presentation context.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import BetterSafariView

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var startingWebAuthenticationSession = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Start WebAuthenticationSession") {
            self.startingWebAuthenticationSession = true
        }
        .webAuthenticationSession(isPresented: $startingWebAuthenticationSession) {
            WebAuthenticationSession(
                url: URL(string: "https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=\(clientID)")!,
                callbackURLScheme: "myapp"
            ) { callbackURL, error in
                print(callbackURL, error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can I ask you a question about oauth on github using swift ui?